# Every collection of measures on a compact space is uniformly tight

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am looking for a proper statement of the sentence in the title and its proof. First, let me give some context.

I have a covariance stationary time series, $X$. The autocovariance function of $X$ is denoted by $\gamma_X(h)$ where $h$ denotes the lag at which autocovariance is computed.

Then I define a sequence of densities on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by
$$f_n(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{h=-n}^n\gamma_X(h)\left(1-\frac{\lvert h \rvert}{n}\right)e^{-ih\lambda}$$

One can show that $f_n$ is real-valued and also nonnegative. For each $n$ I generate a measure $F_n$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by taking $f_n$ as $F_n$'s density with respect to Lebesgue measure. One can also show that $F_n[-\pi,\pi] = \gamma_X(0) < \infty$.

The next statement in the proof I am reading tripped me a bit. It says *since $[-\pi,\pi]$ is compact, $(F_n)_n$ is uniformly tight.* What I want to know is exactly which properties of $F_n$ the author uses to make this claim. Can someone give the most general result on this and its proof (within probability theory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is much less scary than it sounds.  Recall that a family of probability measures $\mathcal{M} =\{\mu_\alpha \}_\alpha$ on a space $X$ is tight if for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a compact set $K_\epsilon \subset X$ so that $$ \mu_\alpha(K_\epsilon) > 1 - \epsilon$$ for every $\alpha$.

Let's quickly note that if $X$ is compact, we can just take $K_\epsilon = X$ and every measure will sat and have no issues.

In your case, you don't have probability measures, but they give $[-\pi,\pi]$ the same amount, so you can divide them all by $\gamma_X(0)$ to get a family of probability measures.